# Change content with Jquery (Paginate)

Tags: jquery

Hy everyone i've been trying for 2 days to modify this script so i can call it whenever a link had the id="paginations" unsuccessful of course ( just because i'm a newb ).

What exactly i am trying to do is call this function to load and change the #content even if the link is inside the #content. Like this.

```
  <div class="pagination">
    <a href="test.php">clik2</a>
  </div>
```

I've trying to create a function and call it with onClick but i was unsuccessful. This script works perfectly if the link is outside the #Content but i need it to work inside the #Content also. Any ideas please ?

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.pagination a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

        $('.pagination a').click(function(){

            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
            $('#content').hide('1000',loadContent);
            $('#load').remove();
            $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load"></span>');
            $('#load').fadeIn('slow');
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
                function loadContent() {
                    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
                }
                function showNewContent() {
                    $('#content').delay(100).show('fast',hideLoader());
                    $(window).scrollTop('');
                }
                function hideLoader() {
                    $('#load').delay(300).fadeOut('fast');
                }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link is being added with javascript, which I think is what you are trying to do then you need to use the live function. Currently you have

```
$('.pagination a').click(
```

Which should be replaced with:

```
$('.pagination a').live('click',function() {
```

You can read more about live [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The problem with click is that it does not get added to elements that are created after the function has been set, where as live will.

Comment: Note that the .live method is deprecated in jQuery 1.7. You should use the .on method for event delegation if you have jQuery 1.7 or higher: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: tnks a lot worked like a charm hope this will help someone else coze this is 1 amaizing script